# disable connection of actual vertex on JGraphX

Tags: java, jgraphx

I need to disable connection of **actual** vertex if edges of vertex >= 2

`if(graph.getModel().getEdgeCount(cell)>=2){
       graphComp.setConnectable(false);    // but for actual cell, not for all vertexes
    }`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mxGraphComponent.setConnectable(false)` you can disable the connection for one Cell by calling `mxCell.setConnectable(false)`.

If you want it to be enabled again when the edgecount goes down again you can use:

```
int maxEdgeCount = 2;

cell.setConnectable(cell.getEdgeCount < maxEdgeCount);
```

Comment: I had the same problem where using "setConnectable" on the graph had no effect. Setting it on the cell worked. Thanks